# How to display associative array in a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table, associative-array, coin-flipping

Can anyone help me? I'm writing a script for a "Luck Game" with the objectives

1. Take user input of any number they wish, generate a random number from 0 to the number they input and display it in a result array.
2. Simulate a game of "Heads or Tails" and also display that result in the same result array (I will be using associative arrays)
3. Run the two objectives above for a total of 6 times.
4. Display the results in a table.
5. Total the amount of 'Heads' and the total amount of 'Tails' each and display them.
6. Return the smallest number out of the 6 results.

I've already completed items 1, 2, and 3.  I just need help on item 6. How to display my results on a 2x7 table with the headings "Coin Side" and "Number" as well as how to sum up all the "heads" and "tails" of the 6 trials, and also return the smallest number generated?

```
 <body>
 <div id = "luckGame"></div>

 var userInput = prompt("Enter maximum number output: ");
 printThis = document.getElementById('luckGame');

 function coinFlip() {
      return (Math.floor(Math.random() < 2) === 0) ? 'Heads' ; 'Tails';
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
      var result = [];

      result["randomNum"] = (Math.floor(Math.random()*userInput);

      result["coin"] = (coinFlip());

     printThis.innerHTML = result["coin"] + " " + result["randomNum"];
     //This loop will run 6 times.
     //This should print for example:  Heads  29 but I need to put all the results 
     //in a 2x7 table with labels "Coin Side" and "Number" included.  How do I do this?
 }

 //Code here needed to sum total of 'Heads' and 'Tails'
 //Code here needed to return the smallest number from the results.

 </body>
```

My CSS for the table

```
 .results {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
   }
```

My rough table

```
 var resultsTable = "<table class= 'results'><tr><td>" + "Coin Side" + "</td><td>" + "Number" + "</td></tr>";
     resultsTable += "<tr><td> + result["coin"] + "</td><td> + result["randomNum"] + </td></tr>";
     ... // repeat 4 more times.
     resultsTable += "<tr><td> + result["coin"] + "</td><td> + result["randomNum"] + </td></tr></table>;
```

If I need to put more details please let me know.

Comment: I'm thinking for the 6 separate results, how can I push each result into one array without "over-writting" it when the loop repeats itself until the loop runs 6 times (I should have 6 separate result values by then).

Comment: Start table html...loop data adding rows ... end table html and insert

Comment: Would be more helpful if maybe you could show me how to do the code to add rows in the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a table with headers

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Coin Side</th><th>Number</th></tr>";
```

Then in your loop simply add this code at the end to add a row to the table

```
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var coinCell = document.createElement("td");
var numCell = document.createElement("td");
coinCell.innerHTML = result["coin"];
numCell.innerHTML = result["randomNum"];
row.appendChild(coinCell);
row.appendChild(numCell);
table.appendChild(row);
```

And finally, add the table to the document

```
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

For counting heads and tails, add this code to your existing loop

```
(result["coin"] === "Heads") ? heads++ : tails++
```

Just create two global variables and set them to zero first

```
var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
```

For getting the min value, first create a global variable set to the max value

```
var min = eval(userInput);
```

Then, in your loop, check if the generated number is less than the current `min`

```
if(result["randomNum"] < min)
  min = result["randomNum"];
```

**Demo**: https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/5/result/

Comment: Thanks, this is so useful for adding rows to tables in a loop.

Comment: If this answer helped, make sure to accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Okay, but one more thing -- I already wrote the code for totaling the sum of 'Heads' and 'Tails' each BUT the loop is reading the words "Heads" and "Tails" as if they were separate characters so instead of only incrementing by +1, they get incremented by +5 each time my loop runs:  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jkvkt4x2/)

Comment: Your code seem to work but the ' if (result < ) ' is giving a syntax error since there's nothing on the other side of the ' < '

Comment: Try it again. I was in the middle of adding that part